# Nativescript app geolication fetch error?

Tags: geolocation, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Friends I am very new to nativescript application. I am try to create a app,

I got error on fetching location

the error is

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: ex.getStatusCode is not a function
JS: TypeError: ex.getStatusCode is not a function
JS:     at file:///data/data/org.nativescript.VivianArmy/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-geolocation/geolocation.js:156:41
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.invoke (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.VivianArmy/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:365:26)
JS:     at Object.onInvoke (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.VivianArmy/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4132:37)
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.invoke (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.VivianArmy/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:364:32)
JS:     at Zone.run (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.VivianArmy/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:125:43)
JS:     at file:///data/data/org.nativescript.VivianArmy/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:760:57
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.VivianArmy/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:398:31)
JS:     at Object.onInvokeTask (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.VivianArmy/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4123:37)
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.VivianArmy/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:397:36)
JS:     at Zone.runTask (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.VivianArmy/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:165:47)
JS:     at drainMicroTaskQueue (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.VivianArmy/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:593:35)
```

Comment: Please provide the code which causes the exception.

Comment: Thanks for your helping mentality, I got the answer

Comment: Maybe answer your own question then? ;)